# Converting a JavaScript snippet to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to convert the following JS snippet into C#, but am having a hard time understanding the implicit types being used.

```
initHuffman = function(size) {
    this.huffmanTree = [];
    var code = 0;
    for (var d = 0; d < (size * 2); d++) {
        var count = this.getBits(size);
        for (var v = 0; v < count; v++) {
            var node = this.huffmanTree;
            for (var d1 = d; d1 !== 0; d1--) {
                var c = (code >> d1) & 1;
                if (!node[c]) node[c] = [];
                node = node[c];
                if (isNumber(node)) return;
            }
            node[code & 1] = this.getBits(size);
            code++;
        }
        code <<= 1;
    }
}
```

This is a function to decode a string of bits into a Huffman tree. The issue I am having is with the `node` object. `node` is of type `any[]`, and references `huffmanTree` which is of type `any[]`.

The first confusing part is `if (!node[c]) node[c] = [];` It seems the code is checking if an index exists in `node`, and if it doesn't, add an empty array?

The second confusing part is `node[code & 1] = this.getBits(size);` The `getBits()` function simply reads a few bits, in this case 4, and returns them as an int. So, it seems `node` can be indexed with ints and with arrays?

How would I accomplish this in C#? What collection or array type could do this?

Running this through the debugger in FireFox gives the following result:

```
0: 0
1: [...]
  0: 1
  1: [...]
    0: 2
    1: [...]
      0: 3
      1: 4
```

I am clearly not understanding what is happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks rather messy, so it would be a lot easier to re-implement this from scratch based on the theory of Huffman tree. Short version is that you will need to write your own `class`es in C# (usually called "leaf nodes" for tree structures), probably also using an interface or inheritance to be able to nest them like this

Comment: *So, it seems node can be indexed with ints and with arrays?* Not really. `code & 1` returns either `0` or `1` depending on `code` being falsy. Nonetheless, this is a prime example of not easy maintainable code.

Comment: i was looking at the huffman tree wikipedia page, and as @UnholySheep was saying, a well written class will take you most of the way